# Eventhandler when a marker / feature is clicked

Tags: openlayers

I googled on this subject and found examples where people are using Overlays to display popups when a marker is clicked or changing the style of the feature when a feature is clicked.

But I want to write a simple event handler which logs the "marker clicked" event. so I don't wan't to display a popup. also I don't want to log any random click on the map. only when the marker/feature icon is clicked.

Finally, in the event handler is there a way to uniquely identify which feature was clicked? like an ID or something? reason for asking is that I generate the list of features from an array and in the event handler I would like to locale the corresponding element from my original array which was used to generate the specific marker that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. Basically, we have to create a "Select" object which has an event handler "on" defined on it. and then attach the Select Object to the map as an interaction.

```
var select = new Select({
  layers: [vectorLayer] // this is the layer which is has your markers/features
});
select.on("select", (function (e) {
   var feature = e.selected[0]
   console.log(feature);
   console.log(feature.get("id"));
}));
map.addInteraction(select);
```